# Is this hard drive about to fail?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mybook

I have a 1TB external WD My Book 1110, last night while I was browsing for some old files in there I started getting data access errors while trying to open a certain folder, everything else seemed OK, although a bit slower than usual, which at the time I had thought it was the computer itself being slow.

I researched online, and ran the cmd to try and find out if there were any errors in the HD using:

> chkdsk G: /f /r

It found many file segments unreadeable, and ultimately the process failed due to a so called unexpected error, I ran it again with the same outcome.

Since that didn't seem to work, I got HD Tune 2.55 and ran the complete error scan text, after many hours it came out basically fine, or at least that's what I thought:

[image]

With the exception of that one little red block there, the rest appeared to be ok. I've had this HD for a few years now but I only use to store stuff I'm not currently using, so it hasn't really had that much use over time, and it never seemed to have a factory defect either, so my question is should I be concerned? I've gone through other files in the HD and haven't had the error again, so I'm not really sure if I should start emergency measures already or if it could've been sort of a false positive.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I got Western Digital Data LifeGuard Diagnostics from the website and ran a quick scan:

[image]

Which failed with this error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try running Western Digitals diagnostics.

Comment: Having some bad sectors does increase the chance that the drive will fail soon, but no-one can agree on how much it increases the chance. As a rule: Always. Make. Backups.

Comment: And if it keeps at 1 bad block for a long time you can (very) slowly start trusting that drive again. I more block follow... shred it.

Comment: I ran diagnostics and updated the question, and sadly this is my backup, I never considered doing a back up's back up, such is life.

Comment: **backup this backup right away !!!**

Comment: Then backup the backups of the backup!

Comment: From [here](http://support.wdc.com/techinfo/general/errorcodes.asp): `During a Quick Test, the self-test failed. Drive should be replaced.`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, i have seen a few with bad sectors last years, others weeks. Western Digital has their own tool for scanning/testing hard drives and repairing bad sectors. Look up the software or downloads available for your product on their site to find it. "Data Lifeguard Diagnostic" it is called.

Comment: I ran diagnostics and updated the question.

Comment: @user1676874 Test failed, in our shop we automatically deem them as BAD hard drives, and recommend immediate replacement. Western Digital should replace it off that result as well, if it is still covered. Take the S/N to Western digital site to check its warranty.

Answer (score 0):

You've run three different types of tests:

1. chkdsk - this is mainly a file system check, and won't tell you anything about the mechanical fitness of the drive, though the /r will check for bad sectors and repair them.  Think of this as the equivalent of checking if the index or the table of contents is correct for your disk.
2. HD Tune Error Scan - This is basically the same as the /r option of chkdsk, and just scans for bad sectors, but again, won't tell you if your drive is experiencing any mechanical issues.
3. WD tool - this runs the actual [SMART self-tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.).  This basically means run the disks on-board diags/self diag, which apparently failed.  As others have mentioned, this is not a good sign, and the drive should be backed up and replaced . . .